# "Go back" twice with next/router

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I have a project in which when the user navigates from page A to page B, I check certain conditions while loading the page (B), if those conditions aren't met I redirect the user to a custom error page (C).

```js
if(!conditionIsMet) {
   Router.push('/customErrorPage')
}
```

Once there, this page (C) offers the user the possibility of *going back* or going to the homepage. The problem I'm having is with the first option. If the user clicks on the *go back* button/link I want to redirect the user to the page before the page that caused the error (A), if not he'll be caught in a loop (B -> C, C -> B, B-> C, etc...). For this I believe I need to "*go back twice*", so `Router.back()` wouldn't work. I have tried `window.history.go(-2)` but that doesn't work either, for some reason I am caught in the loop I described.
Do you have any suggestions? Is there a way I can *go back twice* using `next/router`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there a reason you don't want that 'go back' button to navigate directly to the A page, without manipulating with history?

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko The problem is that A is not always the same, once in C (or B) I don't know where I came from (so I can't redirect the user directly to A).